# R-Subsetting a data frame conditional to related values

Tags: r

I have such a data frame(df):

```
col1  col2
a     2      
a     3 
b     7
b     5
c     4
c     2
c     1
d     5
d     7
```

Namely;

```
df<-data.frame(col1=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c","d","d"), col2=c(2,3,7,5,4,2,1,5,7))
```

Desired output data frame(df1) is:

```
col1  col2
b     7
b     5
d     5
d     7
```

For example,

first row of df in col1 is 2. Related col1 value is "a". Then delete all rows which include "a" in col1. In the same way, 6th row of col2 is equal to 2. Related col1 value is equal to "c". Then delete all rows which include "c" in col1.

How can I do that using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to add a short explanation. It's dirty, but it just subsets df based on a condition. It finds those unique col1 values which have col2 values less than or equal to 2 and removes them from df. 


`df[-which(df$col1 %in% unique(df$col1[which(df$col2 <=2)])),]`

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking: `df[with(df, ave(col2 == 2, col1, FUN = Negate(any))), ]` ?

Comment: @Ted Dallas, thanks also for your solution:) . And also thanks to rawr:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[!col1 %in% col1[col2==2]]]
#    col1 col2
#1:    b    7
#2:    b    5
#3:    d    5
#4:    d    7
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, !col1 %in% col1[col2==2])
```

Comment: No love for the base R solution(s)?! :)  

@akrun 's solution is solid though.

Comment: @akrun You can formulate your second solution also with base R `subset(df,!col1%in%col1[col2==2])`

Comment: @cryo111 Thanks, yes it can be done.  I see that you posted the solution and deleted it.  Why did you delete it?

Comment: @akrun I deleted it because I saw that it was just a minor change to your solution. But I can undelete it.

Answer (score 2):

Base solution with `subset`.

```
subset(df,!col1%in%col1[col2==2])
```